# axa-fr/react-oidc broke navigation to previous page after dependency displays internally page?

Tags: react-tsx, react-oidc

i got the auth up and running, but i have a problem when landing on a error page from the auth dependency (axa-fr/react-ocid). When landing on a dependency internal page (has no actual route) that shows the error, the navigation seems to break, but i can't figure out why. When you push the Browsers back button, the url changes but no rerender happens or the website changes to the website visited before my own page. How can i fix this?

I used this example project, which has the same problem:
https://github.com/mehmetyilmaz001/react-oidc-example

The creator seems to have the same issue:
https://github.com/AxaFrance/react-oidc

Just change the "authority" to a non-valid and you see the problem when login and going back to previous page.

Maybe i miss out something, but i hope you guys can track it down.

Thank you for your help.

I don't know how to handle this, i tried lots of things around the dependency. The navigation should go back to the previous page as expected.